# js/html5 Displaying local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Is there a simple way to display my local storage with **document.write** or **document.innerHTML** methods? It's being stored on 1 page, trying to display on separate. I'm new to js and just unsure how to build the syntax of those methods with how I'm storing it(if possible).

```
 $('form').submit(function() {
    var person = $("#FirstName").val() + "." + $('#LastName').val();
 $('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val(),
       name = $(this).attr('name');
       localStorage[person + "." + name] = value;
       window.location.href = "Confirmation.html";
    console.log('stored key: '+name+' stored value: '+value);
});   
});
```

heres the whole if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/EUWFN/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As local storage is Object, you can go trough all it keys and get in values in simple way

```
for (var key in localStorage) {
  console.log(key + ':' + localStorage[key]);
}
```

To print it to the screen you can use something like this:

```
var output = ''; 

for (var key in localStorage) {
  output = output+(key + ':' +localStorage[key])+'\n';
}

$('#DivToPrintOut').html(output);
```

Comment: does this print the localstorage to the page or just in the console?

Comment: @user2912336, you can print `localStorage[key]` any way you want. For example `$('.someclass').html(localStorage['key_name'])` or `document.write(localStorage['blahblah'])`.

Comment: what if these keys etc are defined on a separate page?

Comment: does not matter on what page they was setted. Localstorage is one for all pages within one domain.

Comment: do you get eny erorrs is console?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Chrome, press F12 for the Developers Tools.

In the Console type `localStorage` and press enter.

Or in your js code put `console.log(localStorage);`.

In the console, click on the little triangle next to line that begins with `Storage`.

Or in Dev Tools:

1. click on the `Resources` tab at the top
2. click on the little triangle next to `Local Storage` in the frame on the left